# NumberFormat class

Tags: java, class, object, number-formatting

So I was thinking that I got the grasp of objects and classes so far but I was quite wrong. Since I'm reading a book on Java I came across NumberFormat class and right now I'm quite confused.

Normally when you would access methods and variables in the class you would use the following code to create an object and with that object you would access the desired methods and variables but It doesn't work like that in this situation.

`NumberFormat formatingExample = new NumberFormat();`

But now I saw in the book that you can actually need to do it this way

`NumberFormat formatingExample = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();`

After that code you can access other methods with the following code

`String price = formatingExample.format(11.5);`

Now I really don't get what all of this code means and what it does. Where is the constructor and how is formatingExample an object now ??? We are calling a static method directly from the NumberFormat class and saving it into a reference variable (NumberFormat) named formating example but what does this method actually do ? Where is the "new" keyword that you use to create an object. I'm quite new to java and just to programming in general so I'm really confused... I thought that got the hang of objects and classes but this  really confused me.

Comment: `getCurrencyInstance()` constructs and sets up a suitable number format object and then returns it for you. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/text/NumberFormat.java#NumberFormat.getInstance%28java.util.Locale%2Cint%29

Comment: @khelwood Ohh so after that it saves the object into the reference variable. And with that varible (object) you can refer to the instance of the class NumberFormat and you can use all the methods located in that class ? This is my understanding on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: What it is and what is does ?
  * The NumberFormat class is abstract class  because it is the base class for every number format in Java (this includes DecimalFormat, for example).

- This design gives you the flexibility of somehow determining the proper subclass instance to return at runtime without making too much of that design rigid at design/compile time. Static methods are exempt from being abstract so a class can work as both a factory and an abstract supertype for concrete implementations.

  There is a public static method in the class i.e

  public static final NumberFormat getInstance()

  This is also a instance of NumberFormat , but it is a concrete instance of a subclass of it.You can't anyhow instantiate an abstract . In this case the method is used to obtain a default formatter for your locale.

Q: Where is the constructor for the class?
Having a constructor for an essentially unknown number format is pretty useless. Bcz it is the base class for other classes, and there is no use of making an instance of unknown number format.

Q: where is the new keyword?
  Since the class is abstract so cant instantiate it directly using new keyword.

Comment: I kinda get it but I probably should look into superclasses, subclases and abstract classes so I can know what they actually do. Thanks for the detailed answer !!

Comment: no problem man :)

Comment: you can give it as a accepted answer if you are clear with the solution.